# как организовать общение между потоками?

Tags: qt

У меня есть два потока, но у меня не получается передать данные между ними.

В общем у меня есть два потока (весь код выложить не могу ибо громоздкий, много всего). Пытался напрямую  положить подсчитанные данные в QLineEdit-ты, но проблема в том что я их инициализирую в главном патоке а расчет происходит в новом потоке. Программа компилируется но не запускается (рун тайм ошибка прыгает от операционной системы)

```
    LE_CAN_ID->setText(QString::number(msg.ID));
    LE_Data_p->setText(DanniePriem);
```

Второй вариант сделать соединение через connect, это вообще пушка тут я разошёлся по полной (дали обезьяне в руки гранату ))) )

Все они не сработали, перепробовал множество вариантов :

```
  connect(LE_CAN_ID, SIGNAL(AcceptedStructured()), this, SLOT(setText(QString::number(msg.ID)));
  connect(LE_Data_p, SIGNAL(), this, SLOT(setText(DanniePriem)));
```

Попробовал postEvent но он в обще мутный один инт передать можно но структуру передать нельзя и это фаиил.

```
   QApplication::postEvent(m_pobjReceiver, pe);
```

Что делать не знаю, подскажите хотя бы нормальное видио про то как сделать общение между потоками.

Comment: есть подозрение, что добавка пятого параметра в функцию `connect` со значением `Qt::QueuedConnection` решит проблему.

Comment: а ещё лучше хоть один `connect` корректно написать... ЗЫ: для объектов из разных потоков `Qt::QueuedConnection` подразумевается...

Comment: не совсем. Если qt не смогла догадаться, что это будут разные потоки, то будет использоваться direct connection.

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "все они не сработали"? Подозреваю, что проблема не в способе соединения, а в сопутствующем коде

Comment: @BeardedBeaver я пытался работать со структурой в двух потоках и пытался перейти из одного потока в главный поток (что бы отобразить результаты), но не вышло

Comment: Ваше "не вышло" не описывает проблему. Ошибка компилцяции? Ошибка в рантайме? Ошибки нет, но данные не поступают? Опишите подробно, что не так, иначе мы тут гадаем на кофейной гуще

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Суть вопроса не получается работать с структурой в двух потоках (ошибка рантайма). Я сформировал чуть более точный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831517/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: **!!!!!!!!!ОТВЕТ!!!!!!!!!** **Ответ на поставленный вопрос, в виде простейшего примера, здесь:** https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831517/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8

Answer (score 1):

Так можно сделать:

```
if(QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread()) {
    LE_CAN_ID->setText(QString::number(msg.ID));
} else {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(LE_CAN_ID, "setText",  Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection,
         Q_ARG(QString, QString::number(msg.ID))
     );
 }
```