# Одна структура, два потока, и работа с ними

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Пытался реализовать двухпоточное приложение, в котором будет одна структура и в обоих потоках будет происходить взаимодействия со структурой.

Общение между двумя потоками сделано через коннекты.

mnogopotochnost.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-05-22T08:22:19
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui concurrent

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mnogopotochnost
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtConcurrent>
//#include <QThread>
#include <QMainWindow>

typedef struct TEST_struct // структура с двумя переменными
{
    int  first;
    int    dwa;
} TEST_struct;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow // класс созданный qt creator-ом
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void otchet(); 

signals:
    void psevdoSignal(); 

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class Two_Class : public QObject{  // второй класс для второго потока
    Q_OBJECT
public:

public slots:
    void schet();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока из за того что
    // обьект прередаваемый moveToThread не должен иметь родителя по этому убираем new QThread(this)
    Two_Class *two_cl = new Two_Class(); // инициализируем второй класс
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), two_cl , SLOT(schet()));

//    connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), two_cl , SLOT(schet()));
    two_cl->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке (второй поток)
}
MainWindow::otchet(){
    TEST_struct str;
    ui->lineEdit->setText(str.first); // отображаем данные структуры
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(str.dwa);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Two_Class::schet(){
    TEST_struct str;
    for(;;){
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
            str.first = i;
            qDebug()<< "Новый поток i =" << i;
            if(i == 450){
                str.dwa = 999; //задаём втрой переменной значение
             //   MainWindow *MW= new MainWindow();
             //   connect(this, SIGNAL(psevdoSignal()), MW, SLOT(otchet())); // связываем второй поток с главным
                connect(this, SIGNAL(psevdoSignal()), MainWindow, SLOT(MainWindow::otchet())); // связываем второй поток с главным
            }
        }
    }
}
```

На mainwindows.ui лежит одна кнопка(PushButton) и два lineEdit-а (lineEdit, lineEdit_2).

Но выпрыгивают разные ошибки. Не могу понять, что не так, ибо это упрощение от моего основного проекта. Где всё работает, но не получается общаться со структурой (где один поток его забирает и не отдаёт).

```
...\Projects\mnogopotochnost\mainwindow.cpp:18: ошибка: prototype for 'int MainWindow::otchet()' does not match any in class 'MainWindow'
 MainWindow::otchet(){
 ^

....\Projects\mnogopotochnost\mainwindow.cpp:1: In file included from mainwindow.cpp:1:0:

....\Projects\mnogopotochnost\mainwindow.h:28: ошибка: candidate is: void MainWindow::otchet()
     void otchet();
          ^
```

Comment: Зачем вы создаете новое окно внутри второго класса? Это же счетный класс, он не должен ничего знать про окно.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver ок убрал //                MainWindow *MW= new MainWindow();

Comment: У каждого из потоков своя структура `TEST_struct`, вы не передаете в слот никаких данных. Такую задачу не стоит пытаться решать через разделяемые данные, достаточно передавать значения посредством сигнал-слотовой связи.

Comment: @BeardedBeaver //  MainWindow *MW= new MainWindow();
                connect(this, SIGNAL(psevdoSignal()), MainWindow, SLOT(MainWindow::otchet())); НО серавно ошибка

Comment: @timob256 вы неправильно по идеологии делаете. Сигнал должен испускаться из класса, выполняющего расчет. Соединение должно быть в окне к слоту приема данных. Делать соединение в классе расчета нельзя, поскольку классу расчета должно быть полностью все равно, кто, как и когда будет пользоваться расчетными данными

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Прочёл несколько раз пару раз в слух, но так и  не чего не понял где соединения делать как их делать.???? Непонятно ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, в котором один поток производит данные, отправляет их в основной поток посредством генерации сигнала.

```
// mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QThread>
#include <QPair>

class VGenerator;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QLineEdit *le1;
    QLineEdit *le2;
    QPushButton *btn;
    QVBoxLayout *box;
    QWidget *cwdg;
    QThread *thread;

    VGenerator *gener;

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void on_update_value(int, int); // слот, ожидающий новые данные
};


class VGenerator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void work(); // метод, генерирующий данные
signals:
    void update(int, int); // сигнал, извещающий о готовности новых данных
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

```
// mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    le1 = new QLineEdit;
    le2 = new QLineEdit;
    btn = new QPushButton("Start");
    box = new QVBoxLayout;
    cwdg = new QWidget;
    thread = new QThread;

    box->addWidget(le1);
    box->addWidget(le2);
    box->addWidget(btn);
    cwdg->setLayout(box);
    setCentralWidget(cwdg);

    gener = new VGenerator;
    gener->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, gener, &VGenerator::work);
    connect(gener, SIGNAL(update(int, int)), this, SLOT(on_update_value(int, int))); // соединение источника данных с приемником
    thread->start();
}

void MainWindow::on_update_value(int v, int sqv)
{
    le1->setText(QString::number(v));
    le2->setText(QString::number(sqv));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}

void VGenerator::work()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        emit update(i, i * i); // генерация сигнала и передача данных
        QThread::msleep(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как я уже описал в комментариях, у вас идеологически неправильно организован обмен данными. Для сферической в вакууме программы "модуль расчета в отдельном потоке с выводом результатов на экран" система должна выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

1. Расчетный класс. Является наследником от `QObject`, имеет сигналы для уведомления внешних классов о прогрессе, результатах расчета и прочих делах. В методах расчетного класса сигналы просто испускаются, никаких соединений не делается.
2. Окно, предназначенное для вывода данных. В окне объявляем слоты с нужным списком параметров, совместимым с сигналами расчетного модуля. Объявляем расчетный модуль, соединяем сигналы расчетного модуля со слотами-обработчиками, перемещаем расчетный модуль в отдельный поток, запускаем расчет.

Замечу, что запуск расчета правильнее производить с помощью сигнала, испускаемого из окна и присоединенного к слоту в классе расчета, а не прямым вызовом.

Таким образом класс расчета ничего не будет знать о том, кто и как будет обрабатывать его сигналы (и будет ли), и вы сможете легко поменять интерфейс в случае необходимости, или вообще сделать консольную версию программы без интерфейса.

З.Ы. У вас синтаксическая ошибка в тексте программы, в заголовочном файле метод `otchet` объявлен как возвращающий `void`, а в файле с кодом без типа, что эквивалентно возвращаемому значению `int`. Об этом вам кстати сказал компилятор, если внимательно прочитать сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: я не знаю по чему, в методе otchet компилятор "ругается" не зависимо от возвращаемого значения, void int я даже создал новый проект(c qt виджетом) и в него пустой положил mainwindows.h  `public slots:
    int AbcSlot(); `   и в сёравно выпрыгивает ошибка  `moc_mainwindow.cpp:71: ошибка: undefined reference to MainWindow::AbcSlot() ` , `collect2.exe:-1: ошибка: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @timob256 покажите код, такая ошибка возникает когда метод, объявленный как слот, не имеет определения, только описание

Comment: извините моя ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу сказать спасибо @Bearded Beaver за хорошее изложение о правильных принципах работы с несколькими потоками, по началу я пытался исправить свои ошибки используя этот ответ. Но увы у меня не вышло. Меня спас ответ @mkkik-а.

У меня возник вопрос кому ставить галочку, ибо ответ @Bearded Beaver-а глобально более полезный (для будущего а галочка прекрасно бы акцентировала внимание на ответе), но ответ @mkkik-а более практичный. Но так как используя только ответ @Bearded Beaver-а у меня не вышло исправить ошибки, то я решил поставить галочку более практичному (на мой взгляд) варианту.

Вот измененные части mainwindows.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtConcurrent>
//#include <QThread>
#include <QMainWindow>

typedef struct TEST_struct // структура с двумя переменными
{
    int  first;
    int    dwa;
} TEST_struct;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow // класс созданный qt creator-ом
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void otchet(int a, int b);

signals:
   int SignalPriem();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

class Two_Class : public QObject{  // второй класс для второго потока
    Q_OBJECT
public:

signals:
    void update(int, int); // сигнал, извещающий о готовности новых данных

 public slots:
    void schet();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QThread *thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока из за того что
    Two_Class *two_cl = new Two_Class(); // инициализируем второй класс
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), two_cl , SLOT(schet()));
    connect(two_cl, SIGNAL(update(int, int)), this, SLOT(otchet(int, int))); // соединение источника данных с приемником
    two_cl->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке (второй поток)
}

void MainWindow::otchet(int a, int b ){
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(a));
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString::number(b));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void Two_Class::schet(){
    TEST_struct str;
    for(;;){
        for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
            str.first = i;
            qDebug()<< "Новый поток i =" << i;
            if(i == 450){
                str.dwa = 999; //задаём втрой переменной значение
                emit update(str.first,str.dwa); // генерация сигнала и передача данных
            }
        }
    }
}
```